# ucsc-bedgraphtobigwig throwing memory allocation error

Tags: ucsc

I installed the latest ucsc-bedgraphtobigwig (v377) with conda in a new enviroment enviroment inmy WSL2.

`conda install -c bioconda ucsc-bedgraphtobigwig`

However, when I try using the package, I am getting his error.

```
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted
```

I tried downloading the package straight from UCSC, and when I run it, I also get some sort of memory error:

```
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted
```

Has anyone experienced something similar? I tried downgrading to v357, and I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Please provide at least the command line you tried and a `head` of the bedGraph and chromsizes file to make this at least partially reproducible.